# Split content of WebRequest with return of key=value

Tags: powershell

I make a WebRequest with PowerShell, the result is like :

```
339631=icmp
339635=ssh
```

How can I split my key and my value in a table?

Comment: what do you mean with a tab? You want to replace the equal sign with a tabular?

Comment: Hello Martin
No, i want to insert it in a board

Comment: What you mean with a board? Can you just write the output you expect?

Comment: Something like that :
`
key     value
-------  ------   
339631     icmp
339635     ssh
`

Comment: You mean a table?

Comment: Yes sorry !  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the result to the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet and specify the equal sign as the delimiter and provide the desired header:

```
<# Your Invoke WebRequest #>  | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '=' -Header 'Key', 'Value'
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
Now the the result is : @{Key=339635; Value=ssh}
Its perfect !

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: :)
Last question, what is the best way for parse the result ?

I need to do a action when key is set to 'ssh' for exemple.

Comment: You now have an object and can pipe it for example to the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter for any desired key.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$var=@"
339631=icmp
339635=ssh
"@

$var | ConvertFrom-StringData
```